# .bat script is evaluating else statement regardless of values within loop

Tags: windows, batch-file, scripting

I have this code block:

```
@echo off

for %%d in (c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z) do (
  if exist "%%d:\Program Files (x86)\" (
    cd /d "%%d:\Program Files (x86)\"
  ) else ( 
     cd /d "%%d:\Folder\subfolder" 2>nul && goto :break
  )
)

:break
if %errorlevel% equ 0 (
  echo "Success, CDing to file location"
) else (
  echo FAILURE
)
```

It prints failure on every single run even though the program files folder clearly exists and it does CD to it. It shouldn't be attempting to evaluate the error condition unless the first one fails. What gives?

Comment: try `IF ERRORLEVEL` instead (no `%`)? http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2008/09/26/8965755.aspx

Comment: Because in certain scenarios this file will be in a different folder. This is just an example.

Comment: This isn't an installer. It's not installing anything. It needs the location to edit a config file. I posted the updated code.

Comment: I understand this. My understanding of the command is "If this location exists, CD to it. Else do this other thing."

In this particular scenario, it's executing as "If this location exists, CD to it, and also do this other thing" which is not what I want.

If I understood why this was occurring I wouldn't have posted here.

Answer (score 1):

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    (for %%d in (c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z) do (
        vol %%d: && (
            cd /d "%%d:\Program Files (x86)\" && goto :break
            cd /d "%%d:\Folder\Subfolder\"    && goto :break
        )
    )) >nul 2>nul 

:break
    if errorlevel 1 (
        echo FAILURE
    ) else (
        echo "Success, CDing to file location"
    )
```

`vol` is used to test if the drive exists (I had to include it to avoid problems with some card readers).

If any of the `cd` operations works, leave the `for` loop.

If there is an error level, the previous code has failed.